# If a curve $x=x(s)$ lies on the sphere whose radius is $a$ and center is at $c$ and whose equation is $(y-c).(y-c)=a^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curves, curvature

> If a curve $x=x(s)$ lies on the sphere whose radius is $a$ and center is at **$c$** and whose equation is $(y-c).(y-c)=a^2$, then show that
> $$
> \begin{align}
> &(i)\quad c=x+\frac1\kappa n-\frac{\kappa '}{\kappa^2\tau }b\\
> &(ii)\quad \frac{d}{ds}\left(\frac{\kappa '}{\kappa^2 \tau}\right)-\frac{\tau}{\kappa}=0\\
> &(iii)\quad \left(\frac{1}{\kappa}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\kappa '}{\kappa^2 \tau}\right)^2=a^2
> \end{align}
> $$
> Where $t,n,b,\kappa$ and $\tau$ are tangent, normal, binormal, curvature and torsion respectively.

From serret-Frenet formulae,
$$
\begin{align}
t' &=\kappa n\\
n' &= -\kappa t + \tau b\\
b' &= \tau n
\end{align}
$$

Since $x=x(s)$ lies on the sphere, I start with differentiating the equation,

$$
\begin{align}
(x-c).(x-c)&=a^2\\
2x'.(x-c)&=0\\
t.(x-c)&=0\\
x't+(x-c).t'&=0\quad\text{differentiating again w.r.t. }s\\
t.t+(x-c).\kappa n &=0\\
(x-c).n &= - \frac{1}{\kappa}
\end{align}
$$

Now I couldn't understand how to go further. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There lacks definition of some variables.

Comment: Added. Let me know if I need to add anything else @aerile

Comment: Let $x-c=a_1 t+a_2 n +a_3 b$. We can evaluate $a_1$ by $(x-c).t$ and so on because $t,n,b$ are orthonormal system.

Comment: Okay, then we have to know what's the value of $(x-c).t,\: (x-c).n$ and $(x-c).b$ @aerile

Comment: Yes, two of them are already obtained in your equations. Differentiating the last equation seems to provide the third one.

Answer (score 1):

You have already obtained
[1] $(x-c).t = 0$
[2] $(x-c).n = -1/κ$

Differenciating the equation [2],
[3] $(x-c).b = κ'/κ^2τ$

As in my comment, these results and the property of $t,n,b$ being orthonormal system imply
[4] $x-c = (-1/κ)n + (κ'/κ^2τ)b$,
which is equivalent to $(i)$.

Further differenciating the equation [3],
[5] $(x-c).(-τn) = d/ds(κ'/κ^2τ)$,
which imply $(ii)$ using [2].
(Here your equation $b'=τn$ is corrected to $b'=-τn$.)

Finally, evaluating $(x-c).(x-c)=a^2$ using [4] will show $(iii)$.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks, @aerile. Actually, I don't understand where I should stop differentiating or continue. I have faced a similar problem with another problem. I will post that issue, if I couldn't manage to solve that. Do you have any suggestion for this kind of difficulties? Or any good resources with great explanation.

Comment: Actually I just tried it but I attempt some explanations. (1) Serret-Frenet formula has three equations so differentiating three times gives three independent equations, or more concretely, (2) κ is defined using t' and τ is defined using n', so at least twice differentiating are needed to obtain equation including τ. This time I just noticed further differentiating works when I was thinking about how to get $d/ds(κ'/κ^2τ)$ in the target equation.